# PHP if Statement never true

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, if-statement

I'm really stuck at this point.

What I'm trying to do is that I generate a table with information from my database.

And behind every information there is a button to change the saved data.

The name of my button is the ID of the current data.

```
<form method='POST'>
  <button type='button' name='".$zeile['ID']."' onclick='edit()'>EDIT BUTTON</button>
</form>
```

So, if I click on the button my div form shows up which looks like this:

```
<div id="edit" onclick="off()">
<form class="newmitarbeiter" method="POST">
 <label>EDIT THIS DATA</label>
 <label>Name: </label>
 <input type="text" name="nachname" value="<?php echo $firstname ?>"></input>
 <label>Vorname: </label>
 <input type="text" name="vorname" value="<?php echo $lastname; ?>"></input>
 <label>Abteilung: </label>
 <input type="text" name="abteilung" value="<?php echo $section; ?>"></input>
 <label>Stockwerk: </label>
 <input type="text" name="stockwerk" value="<?php echo $floor; ?>"></input>
 <br/><br/>
 <input name="hinzufuegen" type="submit" value="Abspeichern" class="hinzufuegen" ></input>
 <input name="abbrechen" type="submit" value="Abbrechen" class="abbrechen" ></input>
</form>
</div>
```

I want that the value of the data is already in the form. 
And to know which EDIT button I've clicked I run a loop which checks if the clicked button's name is a specific number.

```
    for($i = 1; $i < 100; $i++){
     if(isset($_POST[$i])){

         SQL query which defines my variables in the form above

        }
    }
```

My problem now is, that I get an error message that my variables in the form are not defined. 
I guess that the if statement never gets true but I don't even know why.

I'd be really thankful if anyone can help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `$_POST` won't have any values unless the form is submitted with `method="post"`. Your form has the correct method, but it has no action to submit to. Unless your `edit()` method submits the form, as it seems it just does some DOM manipulation to show the edit form, then you'll never have a value for `$_POST` here.

Comment: Not related, but fyi: `name="nachname" value="<?php echo $firstname ?>` You got firstname/lastname mixed up

Comment: You could add a hidden input field that has the id as value to your form to know which edit button/form you submitted

Answer (score 0):

The key values of $_POST are determined by the name attribute of the *submitting* form's inputs. You do not have any element with names in the range of 1-100 under your edit form.

When you submit, either $_POST["hinzufuegen"] or $_POST["abbrechen"] will be set.

To know which ID is used, you will need to make a few changes.

Change

```
<form method='POST'>
  <button type='button' name='".$zeile['ID']."' onclick='edit()'>EDIT BUTTON</button>
</form>
```

to

```
<button type='button' onclick='edit(<?=$zeile['ID']?>)'>EDIT BUTTON</button>
```

(Note - I have removed the wrapping form tag and the name attribute. They will not be used when submitting the form so I have just some the useless markup here.)

and add the following hidden input to your edit form

```
<input type="hidden" id="dataID" name="dataID"/>
```

Your JS edit() method will need to be modified to accept the ID of the data you'd like to deal with. You would need to set this ID to the new hidden input in the edit form, so something like -

```
function edit(dataID)
{
   document.getElementById("dataID").value = dataID
}
```

Then, you can know exactly which ID was used with $_POST["dataID"]

Comment: Have already solved it by giving the POST variables into SESSION variables in another page, but still thank you very much for your help!